Compute the integral: $\int_{1}^{2024}\text{lcm}(\left\lfloor \sqrt[9]{x} \right\rfloor, \left\lfloor \sqrt[10]{x} \right\rfloor)dx$.
I splitted it up in cases as usual:
$$\int_{1}^{2024}\text{lcm}(\left\lfloor \sqrt[9]{x} \right\rfloor, \left\lfloor \sqrt[10]{x} \right\rfloor)dx = \int_1^{2^9}\text{lcm}(1,1)dx+\int_{2^9}^{2^{10}}\text{lcm}(2,1)dx+\int_{2^{10}}^{2024}\text{lcm}(2,2)dx$$
$$=\int_1^{2^9}1dx+\int_{2^9}^{2024}2dx = 3535.$$
However, it seems that the actual answer is supposed to be $5535$ instead. Where did I go wrong?

The novelty of this question, coupled with the 2024 found in the question, suggests that this is probably some kind of contest problem. Contest problems are fine here, so long as you specify which contest it comes from, so we can verify that the contest has closed. Where did this question come from?

I double checked the answer on desmos and the answer it gave me was 3535. Are you sure that the correct answer is meant to be 5535?

For it to be 5535, the function under the integral must be greater than 2 at least somewhere, and that's obviously not the case.

$\int_1^{2^9} 1 , dx+\int_{2^9}^{2^{10}} 2 , dx+\int_{2^{10}}^{2024} 4 , dx=5535$

@TheoBendit it's actually from UC Berkeley integration bee 2022, they just had 2024 by accident.

@MariuszIwaniuk I thought lcm(2,2)=2?

@LiamVerdon For some reason WolframAlpha says 5535, but Desmos does say 3535, which is strange...

The least common multiple of $2$ and $2$ is $2$. Mariusz Iwaniuk is just offering a possible explanation of where the incorrect answer $5535$ came from. Why WolframAlpha would think it was $4$ instead of $2$ is beyond me.
